# Using multiple exceptions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Is there a way to use multiple exceptions in python? Like code below:

```
try:
   #mycode
except AttributeError TypeError ValueError:
   #my exception
```

What I mean is how to use  `AttributeError` `TypeError` `ValueError` with each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a tuple:

```
try:
   # mycode
except (AttributeError, TypeError, ValueError):
   # catches any of the three exception types above
```

Quoting the [reference `try` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> When an exception occurs in the `try` suite, a search for an exception handler is started. This search inspects the except clauses in turn until one is found that matches the exception.
>   *[...]*
>   For an except clause with an expression, that expression is evaluated, and the clause matches the exception if the resulting object is “compatible” with the exception. An object is compatible with an exception if it is the class or a base class of the exception object **or a tuple containing an item compatible with the exception**.

Emphasis mine.