# How do I handle different errors when working with an API?

Tags: python

I am working a project in Python were I am gathering rain data and in this case temperature data from the Netatmo weather stations (Its basically just a private weather station you can set up in you garden and it will collect rain data, temperature, wind etc.)

When using the patatmo API you need a user with credential, a client. This client then has 500 requests pr. Hour which can be used on different requests, among these are the `client.GetPublicdata` request and the `client.Getmeassure request`. The `Getmeassure` request requires a station id and a module id, which I get from the the `Getpuclicdat` request. If I run out of requests I will catch that error using the except `ApiResponseError`: and I will then change the client credentials since I am not alone in this project and have credentials from two other people. My issues are:

If a station or module ID is not found using the `Getmeassure` request it will return a different type of `ApiResponseError`, which in my current code also is caught in the previously mentioned `except`, and this results in an endless loop where the code just changes credential all the time.

The code looks like this:

```
from patatmo.api.errors import ApiResponseError
...
...
...
a_test1 = 0
        while a_test1 == 0:
            try:
                Outdoor_data = client.Getmeasure(
                        device_id = stations_id , 
                        module_id = modul_ID , 
                        type = typ ,
                        real_time = True ,
                        date_begin = Start  , 
                        date_end = End
                        )
                time.sleep(p)
                a_test1 = 1
            except ApiResponseError:
                credentials = cred_dict[next(ns)]
                client = patatmo.api.client.NetatmoClient()
                client.authentication.credentials = credentials
                client.authentication.tmpfile = 'temp_auth.json'
                print('Changeing credentials')
                credError = credError + 1
                if credError > 4:
                    time.sleep(600)
                    credError = 0
                pass
            except:
                print('Request Error')
                time.sleep(p)
```

The documentation for the `error.py` script, that was made by someone else, looks like this:

```
class ApiResponseError(BaseException):
    pass

class InvalidCredentialsError(ApiResponseError):
    pass

class InvalidApiInputError(BaseException):
    pass

class InvalidRegionError(InvalidApiInputError):
    def __init__(self):
        message = \
            ("'region' required keys: "
             "lat_ne [-85;85], lat_sw [-85;85], "
             "lon_ne [-180;180] and lon_sw [-180;180] "
             "with lat_ne > lat_sw and lon_ne > lon_sw")
        super().__init__(message)


class InvalidRequiredDataError(InvalidApiInputError):
    def __init__(self):
        message = "'required_data' must be None or in {}".format(
            GETPUBLICDATA_ALLOWED_REQUIRED_DATA)
        super().__init__(message)


class InvalidApiRequestInputError(BaseException):
    pass


class InvalidPayloadError(InvalidApiRequestInputError):
    pass


API_ERRORS = {
    "invalid_client": InvalidCredentialsError("wrong credentials"),
    "invalid_request": ApiResponseError("invalid request"),
    "invalid_grant": ApiResponseError("invalid grant"),
    "Device not found": ApiResponseError("Device not found - Check Device ID "
                                         "and permissions")
}
```

What I want to do is catch the error depending what type of error I get, and I just doesn't seem to have any luck doing so

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiple exceptions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287886/using-multiple-exceptions-in-python)

Comment: It wouldnt.  He wants to differentiate exception classes via multiple except clauses, not necessarily put them together in a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which of those exceptions subclasses do you get on request overrun?  Use only that one to drive the auth swap.  If it’s not a particular one but is shared with other bad events, you will need to examine the exception’s variables. Also you will need to figure out which exception to work around - bad station id might mean someone is offline so ignore and try later.  Vs logic flaws in your program, abend on those, fix, retry.

Exception handling is on a first-catch, first-handled basis.  Your most specific classes have to do the “except” first to match first, else a generic one would grab it and handle it. Watch your APIs exception hierarchy carefully!

```
maxexc = 1000
countexc = 1
while ...
  # slow your loop
  time.sleep(p)
  try:
    ... what you normally do


  # dont use the too generic ApiResponseError here yet
  except requestoverrunexception as e:
    ... swap credendentials
    countexc+=1 

  except regionexception as e:
    ... ignore this region for a while
    countexc += 1

  # whoops abend and fix
  except ApiResponseError as e:
    print vars(e)
    raise
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise
```

I would bail after too many exceptions, thats what countexc is about.

Also 500 requests an hour seems generous.  Don’t try to fudge that unless you have a real need.  Some providers may even have watchdogs and get rid of you if you abuse them.

Comment: The error message for having used the last request is  Raise API_ERRORS.get(error , ApiResponseError(error)) , and it then gives you and error called "User usage reached". This I find weird since i only see 4 different keys in the API_ERRORS dict and none of these are "User usage reached". I will keep keep your no fudgeing recommendation in mind. Also thanks for the answer i hope i will be able to figure out a solution based on it. (Sorry for the formatting of this comment, i have not yet fully figured out how it works on this site)